# Could not find file error on uploading files in asp.net application webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, webforms

I want to upload files like images using `asp.net application webforms`.
The application `.netfaramwork` is `4.6.1`.
I don't have any problem with website projects but webforms throw unusual errors.
This is my `aspx` page code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="uploadfile.aspx.cs" Inherits="fileUploadTest.uploadfile" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>upload image</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <p>Browse to Upload File</p>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload File" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </p>
    </form>
    <p>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="FileUploadStatus"></asp:Label>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

and in code behind `aspx.cs` is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace fileUploadTest
{
    public partial class uploadfile : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((FileUpload1.PostedFile != null) && (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
            {
                string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("upload") + "\\" + fn;
                try
                {
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
                    FileUploadStatus.Text = "The file has been uploaded.";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    FileUploadStatus.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                FileUploadStatus.Text = "Please select a file to upload.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I already create a folder in `application` root named it `upload`.
[image]
But when I click on the button after choosing the file from my system, it throws an error as following:

> Error: Could not find file 'C:\Users\mybla\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\05. Learning\fileUploadTest\fileUploadTest\upload\logo.png'.

`logo.png` is the file I choose from my system. I even Try this code:

```
if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/upload/"))){
      FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/upload/" + fileName));
}
```

`Directory.Exists()` returns `true` but `FileUpload1.SaveAs()` return same error I mentioned.
**Note: Update#1**
I even try following code, but the error is same:

```
 var path = Server.MapPath("~/upload/" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
 FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct and I suppose your `windows defender` on `windows 10` block the IIS access due to it's new feature `controlled folder access`.
To resolve your problem:
 
1. open the windows defender.
2. click on `manage ransomware protection` on `virus and threat protection` tab.
3. then switch off `controlled folder access`.
Tell me if you have still problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most of all problem occurs because of non-existed directory.
Place this code before calling `.SaveAs` and give it a one more try:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("upload")))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("upload"));
}
```

**Update**
Here is complete `Button1_Click` event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((FileUpload1.PostedFile != null) && (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
    {
        string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("upload") + "\\" + fn;
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("upload")))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("upload"));
            }
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
            FileUploadStatus.Text = "The file has been uploaded.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            FileUploadStatus.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        FileUploadStatus.Text = "Please select a file to upload.";
    }
}
```

Comment: nope. I try your code too. but as I said before I test with Directory.Exists() and I realize the directory exists.

Comment: I completely reproduced your project and it indeed throws this error using code behind you provided, but as soon as you add snippet from my answer - it works fine as requested folder is available now. I updated my answer with completed Button1_Click

Comment: thanks but still the same error. I suspected to my window10 defender so I will test my program on another system with windows 8.1.

Comment: tell us what was the result?

Comment: I was able to run on Windows 8.1 without any problems.

Comment: OK I Know what is your problem

Answer (score 0):

Save the file with extension like below.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((FileUpload1.PostedFile != null) && (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
        {
            string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("~/upload/");
            try
            {
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation+fn +ext);
                FileUploadStatus.Text = "The file has been uploaded.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                FileUploadStatus.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FileUploadStatus.Text = "Please select a file to upload.";
        }
    }
```